# SAS options not persistent on SAS Server

Tags: sas

I am using this

```
signoff;
*** REMOVED CONNECTION BLOCK;
signon;

rsubmit;

%put REUSE= %sysfunc(
     getoption(REUSE)); *says no;
%put COMPRESS= %sysfunc(
     getoption(REUSE)); *says no;

options compress=YES;
options reuse=YES;

endrsubmit;
```

And even after the option is set, whenever I reconnect it will say NO/NO for these two options.
How do I make them persistent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the session is ending with endrsubmit;

To persist the session:

```
rsubmit persist=yes;
```

Comment: Thanks! So it's only session wide though, we can't have a Server persist to be shared across all sessions?

Comment: I imagine you would have to talk to the server admin to have the server's defaults changed.  Although, at least with EG I think there *might* be some additional flexibility there on a per-user basis - but that's beyond my experience, just a random memory.

Answer (score 1):

One option for having settings persist across sessions is to use a custom autoexec file. Assuming you have access to edit your .ini file that contains the connection script, you can add `-autoexec myfile.sas` to that script, which would cause `myfile.sas` to be executed upon server connection.